# React MUI select not working when I wrap menu item with Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

My code looks something like this.

```
return(
 <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 80 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-autowidth"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          autoWidth
          label="Age"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <Tooltip describeChild title="Tewnty">
            <MenuItem value={10}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          </Tooltip>
          <MenuItem value={21}>Twenty one</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={22}>Twenty one and a half</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
)
```

Whenever i click on menu item nothing happens means select item does not gets updated.

Comment: what is inside handleChange function

Comment: const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Tooltip` inside `MenuItem` and add `div` tag as tooltip expects child element

```
<MenuItem value={10}>
   <Tooltip title="Twenty">
       <div>Twenty</div>
   </Tooltip>
</MenuItem>
```